# using akka streams for downloading binary data from server

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

while working with streams, I started to abstract my download handling into a `RunnableGraph`.

in this `Graph` I use one url to start my download process, I request a `HttpResponse` from url and evaluate the `StatusCode`. If there is a `Redirect` response, my process gives that `Location` header value to requestProcessor and try to download that again.
If 200 receives, my process accumulate binary and send it to my sink.

My Problem: [here](https://gist.github.com/SourceCodeBot/2c401b8a2aacdedcc8ca4a7f244a3887#file-downloadgraph-scala-L64) is my out push statement and that sink will never receive any data :(

I hope my custom `FlowShape` is written right, but may there is an issue hidden.

Comment: You call push inside of an asynchronously executed Future.onComplete handler. That will not work, you will have to use `getAsyncCallback` to safely signal completion to the GraphStage. See https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-customize.html#using-asynchronous-side-channels for more information.

Comment: All that said, this use case doesn't seem like a streaming use case and you will be able to simplify your code a lot by just using Future composition to achieve what you are after.

Comment: https://github.com/akka/akka-http/issues/195 has a few examples how to do redirection handling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getAsyncCallback` works for my issue how [jrudolph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7647/jrudolph) described in comment.

changed code to:

```scala
def onGrab(current: HttpResponse): Unit = {
   if (redirectCodes.contains(current.status) && current.header[Location].isDefined) {
     push[String](redirect, current.header[Location].get.value())
     current.entity.discardBytes()
     pull(in)
   } else {
     logger.debug("download . . .")
     current
       .entity
       .dataBytes
       .map(_.toArray)
       .runWith(Sink.head)
       .foreach(
         getAsyncCallback[Array[Byte]](value => push(out, value)).invoke
     )
   }
}
```